# Running/Debugging Flutter app very slow after upgrading to latest SDK version 1.20.4

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm facing this problem after upgrading to latest stable version 1.20.4
Earlier I was using Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 and debug/run speed was good enough.
Is anyone else also facing this issue? Or could anyone help by suggesting some solutions or reasons as to why this is happening?
I am using a Windows 10 machine.
Running `flutter doctor -v` yields the following output

````
    • Flutter version 1.20.4 at D:\flutter
    • Framework revision fba99f6cf9 (8 days ago), 2020-09-14 15:32:52 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\amani\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\amani\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.49.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\amani\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.14.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the issue by deleting Flutter SDK and then replacing it with newly downloaded SDK.
It seems that upgrade caused some files to get corrupted in the SDK directory.

Comment: I was starting to think that my phone was the problem... Thanks mate!

Comment: What a life saver!! I would have spent hours on this. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

i had a simular issue , for me i return to the previous stable version and everything goes good ,
run `flutter downgrade` to return to the previous fluter version install on your machine

Comment: but that would just be a temporary fix :(

Comment: the speed depends mainly on your hardware specifications , it's true that it may be a temporary solution but better than spend all your time , i search for a solution but almost every one was doing this , and this worked for me as well

Comment: I do understand that, and finally it's solved. It seems that on running flutter upgrade caused some changes to the existing SDK on the system which resulted to the issue.