# Flutter the release application is slower than the debug version

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, dart, mobile

I wanted to compare the performance of Flutter with React Native. So I wrote a simple number sorting program that I run in the Flutter app. To my surprise, the debug version is much faster than the release version of the app.
I have already tried generating apk versions with various flutter commands but to no effect.
Could this be the cause? How to solve this problem?

I will add that the flutter app in the release version is slower than the app in the release version in React Native which seems strange due to the fact that Flutter is compiled almost to a native language and React Native has to be interpreted.
The debug version of Flutter is faster than the release version of React Native.

Please help.

flutter doctor -v

```
• Flutter version 2.0.3 at C:\src\flutter
• Framework revision 4d7946a68d (3 months ago), 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
• Engine revision 3459eb2436
• Dart version 2.12.2
```

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java
• Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
• Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
(or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.3)
• IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.3
• Flutter plugin version 55.1.4
• Dart plugin version 203.7759

Comment: Please add `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: And have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011934/running-debugging-flutter-app-very-slow-after-upgrading-to-latest-sdk-version-1 maybe some files got corrupted

Comment: @Nuts, I just added.

Comment: @Nuts, No. My problem is not that the apps have slowed down, but that the release version is slower than the debug version which is absurd. I searched all over the internet and found several posts with a similar problem to mine, for example:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19677
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31552
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51199 
but I couldn't find a clear answer there. 
I would appreciate your help.